# vim: erase key moves over character instead of deleting it. on retyping, prev characters do not change right away

Tags: vim

when i type a line say

Happy new

and then <backspace><backspace> and then retype

the old characters stay around until i type 3 or 4 characters.

This is very disorienting.

Comment: are you sure you are in insert mode? press 'i' and see if this continutes?

Comment: Are you trying to learn vim, or do you know how to use vim but it's broken for some reason?

Answer (score 2):

This happens when vim is in "vi compatible" mode; I'm not sure exactly which option controls the behaviour, probably ":set backspace".

Doing ":set nocompatible" will make it behave as you expect; if you don't have expectations like that, doing ":set nocompatible" is probably a good thing.

Comment: Thanks janm. I have no idea why I did :set cp. Vim works a lot better now.